# EditText Click in CursorAdapter alter my view

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-cursoradapter

Hi everybody I'm new in android. I am getting a problem in CursorAdapter. My UI is as follow[image]

Problem -

1. When I click on Plus button without click on EditText, then it working fine , means adding that item to database. Suppose I click on “Aloo Tikki” Plus button then “Aloo Tikki ” goes in database.
2. When I click on EditText and then click Plus Button then some thing else goes data base. Suppose I click on EditText and then Plus Button of “Aloo Tikki” , then “Reshmi kabab ” goes to database. If I click on EditText and then Plus button of “Corn Tikki” then “Tandori chiken” goes in data base.

   ```
   Without click on EditText it working fine as I wish.
   ```

I am going to post my CursorAdapter code

```
         public class CustAdpt extends CursorAdapter{
private Context mContext;
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
Cursor cursor, c;

private String str_item_id;   
private String str_item_type;   
private String str_item_name;         
private String str_item_cost;     
String str_edt_txt_change;
int quantity =1;
double amount =0;
int int_edttxt =2;
int block_not_chk_for_first_click ;         
ViewHolder holder;
SQLiteDatabase dh = DatabaseHelpereKOT.getInstance().getDb();

public CustAdpt(Context context, Cursor c) {
    super(context, c);
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    mContext = context;
    cursor = c;
    System.out.println("cuntrutor custAdpt");

}


@Override   
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    System.out.println("inside bind view");
    holder.setImType((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.veg_nv_image));
    holder.setTvTitle((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_name));
    holder.setTvPrice((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_cost));
    holder.getTvTitle().setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("item_name")));
    holder.getTvPrice().setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Item_cost")));


    int _id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));
    view.setTag(R.id.item_name, _id);
    String type = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("item_type"));
    if (type.trim().startsWith("n") || type.trim().startsWith("N")) {    
        //holder.getImType().setPadding(6, 0, 0, 0);
        holder.getImType().setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.non_veg);
    } else {  
        holder.getImType().setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.veg);
    }
    System.out.println("end of bind view");

}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder_newview;     
    c = cursor;
    View convertView;
    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_data_item, parent, false);

    System.out.println("only once calling of new view method");   
    block_not_chk_for_first_click =1;
    holder_newview = new ViewHolder();
    holder_newview.setId(cursor.getInt(0));  
    System.out.println("check edit text click 11111");
    ((ImageView) (convertView.findViewById(R.id.add_image)))
            .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {      
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    System.out.println("button click");       
                    System.out.println("quantity for item :::::::"+int_edttxt);

                    addToDB(holder_newview.getId());

                    System.out.println("i m in ryt [palce");

                }
            });   
    convertView.setTag(holder_newview);
    System.out.println("check edit text click 222222");
    return convertView;         

}
void addToDB(Integer objId) {
    if (objId != null) {
        int _id = objId;
        boolean flag = true;
        System.out.println("on Add button click "+_id);
        Cursor cursor = dh.query(DatabaseHelpereKOT.RESTAURANT_menu_temp,
                new String[] { "_id", "item_id", "item_type", "item_name","Item_cost"},"_id=?", new String[] { String
                        .valueOf(_id) }, null, null, null);  

        if ((cursor != null) && (cursor.getCount() > 0)
                && cursor.moveToFirst() ) 
        {
            str_item_id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("item_id"));
            str_item_type = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("item_type"));
            str_item_name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("item_name"));
            str_item_cost = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Item_cost"));
            amount = int_edttxt*Integer.parseInt(str_item_cost);
            System.out.println("iten name  ::::::::: "+str_item_name);

                    cursor.close();




            ContentValues orderValues = new ContentValues();    
            orderValues.put("item_id", str_item_id);
            orderValues.put("item_type", str_item_type);
            orderValues.put("item_name", str_item_name);
            orderValues.put("Item_cost", str_item_cost);
            orderValues.put("qty", int_edttxt);
            orderValues.put("amount", amount);  
            dh.insert(DatabaseHelpereKOT.RESTAURANT_menu_order, null, orderValues);

            block_not_chk_for_first_click =2;   
            System.out.println("block not chk after insertion"+block_not_chk_for_first_click);
            System.out.println("data inserted at order");
            String msg = "Menu Item Added Successfully";
            Message msgObject = new Message();
            msgObject.what = 1;
            msgObject.obj = msg;
            addMenuItemHandler.sendMessage(msgObject);    

        }        
    }
}
public Handler addMenuItemHandler = new Handler() {

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
        if (msg.what == 1) {
            System.out.println("inside handler");
            Toast.makeText(mContext, (String) msg.obj, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();  
        }
    };

};
   }
```

Now this is going to post my list_data_item.xml

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutMainBody"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5px"
    android:layout_marginTop="5px"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/add_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/add_to_db_1" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/separator_info_add"
        android:layout_width="22sp"
        android:layout_height="2sp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/add_image"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/main_body_item_title_first_pics"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/separator_info_add"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="clickHandler"
        android:src="@drawable/add_item_order"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_cost"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/main_body_item_title_first_pics"
        android:text="$00"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="18dip"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:typeface="serif" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/veg_nv_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/main_body_item_pics2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/veg_nv_image"
        android:src="@drawable/add_item_order"
        android:textSize="20dip"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/main_body_item_pics2"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textColor="@color/Txt_color_menu_list"
        android:textSize="20dip"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/main_body_item_title_description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/item_name"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dip"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/item_cost"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/main_body_item_pics2"
        android:text="title description"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="16dip"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtxt_qty_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/item_cost"
        android:ems="5"
        android:hint="Qty"


        android:inputType="number"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColorHint="@color/Txt_color_menu_list" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>
</RelativeLayout>

<View
    android:id="@+id/separator_bottom"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="10sp"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:visibility="invisible" />
```

I can't understand why EditText's Click alter Plus Click. Any help is really appreciated.  Please some help me , It is SOS situation. Thanks in advance to all.

Comment: A better approach would be to store all values and provide a save button at the bottom, once all your fields are populated in an array list or hash map put them into the database using a Async Task. Fool Proof! In the above case you need to use a boolean array to remember the place of the button click, which entry goes where, in detail:What it is troubling here in your case is, your onclick listener which belongs to say 5th item. wil be assigned to row2-5 on screen. Using view.setTag() in Adapter and in single onclick listener, it can be solved, by retrieving the tag of the view.

Comment: @NunChai.. Thanks for your reply......As you told it can be solved by "retrieving the tag of the view". Will you please elaborate this for me in context of my code. It will really helpful . Please help me

Comment: and there is a problem maintaining `convertView` as global. when `newView()` is called, `convertView` will change to this `newView`. i.e. now `convertView` will point the last view in list. and when clicking on any plus button, you are saving based on the value of `convertView`. if you click on any plus button, always the details of last row will be saved.

Comment: @GopalRao..Thanks for quick replay

Comment: @GopalRao....Now i define convertView in newView block , but still i am getting same issue.

Comment: public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
  final ViewHolder holder;
  c = cursor;
  View convertView;
  convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_data_item, parent, false);

Comment: @BlueGreen edit your question with updated code...

Comment: @BlueGreen and also remove the global reference of `ViewHolder`...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48340/discussion-between-blue-green-and-gopal-rao)

Comment: @GopalRao...After implementing both of your suggestion still not working as well as i update my question. Please Mr.Gopal help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem by maintaining `ViewHolder` and `convertView` as global references. These values will get updated when `newView()` is called every time. and with respect to comments, this will help you...

```
public class SampleAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    private String str_item_id;
    private String str_item_type;
    private String str_item_name;
    private String str_item_cost;
    String str_edt_txt_change;
    int quantity = 1;
    double amount = 0;
    int int_edttxt = 2;
    int block_not_chk_for_first_click;
    SQLiteDatabase dh = DatabaseHelpereKOT.getInstance().getDb();

    public SampleAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
        super(context, c);
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        System.out.println("inside bind view");
        holder.getTvTitle().setText(
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("item_name")));
        holder.getTvPrice().setText(
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Item_cost")));

        int _id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));
        view.setTag(R.id.item_name, _id);
        String type = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("item_type"));
        if (type.trim().startsWith("n") || type.trim().startsWith("N")) {
            // holder.getImType().setPadding(6, 0, 0, 0);
            holder.getImType().setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.non_veg);
        } else {
            holder.getImType().setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.veg);
        }
        int ID = cursor.getInt(0);
        holder.getAddImage().setTag(ID);
        holder.getAddImage().setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                System.out.println("button click");
                System.out.println("quantity for item :::::::" + int_edttxt);
                int id = (Integer) v.getTag();
                addToDB(id);
                System.out.println("i m in ryt [palce");
                View parent = (View) v.getParent();
                EditText editText = (EditText) parent.findViewById(R.id.edtxt_qty_id);
                String text = editText.getText().toString();
                // Now you got the text in EditText. You can save this text
            }
        });
        System.out.println("end of bind view");
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        View convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_data_item, parent,
                false);
        block_not_chk_for_first_click = 1;
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.add_image);
        holder.setAddImage(imageView);
        holder.setImType((ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.veg_nv_image));
        holder.setTvTitle((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_name));
        holder.setTvPrice((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_cost));
        convertView.setTag(holder);
        System.out.println("check edit text click 222222");
        return convertView;

    }

    void addToDB(Integer objId) {
        if (objId != null) {
            int _id = objId;
            boolean flag = true;
            System.out.println("on Add button click " + _id);
            Cursor cursor = dh.query(DatabaseHelpereKOT.RESTAURANT_menu_temp,
                    new String[] { "_id", "item_id", "item_type", "item_name",
                            "Item_cost" }, "_id=?",
                    new String[] { String.valueOf(_id) }, null, null, null);

            if ((cursor != null) && (cursor.getCount() > 0)
                    && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                str_item_id = cursor
                        .getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("item_id"));
                str_item_type = cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex("item_type"));
                str_item_name = cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex("item_name"));
                str_item_cost = cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex("Item_cost"));
                amount = int_edttxt * Integer.parseInt(str_item_cost);
                System.out.println("iten name  ::::::::: " + str_item_name);

                cursor.close();

                ContentValues orderValues = new ContentValues();
                orderValues.put("item_id", str_item_id);
                orderValues.put("item_type", str_item_type);
                orderValues.put("item_name", str_item_name);
                orderValues.put("Item_cost", str_item_cost);
                orderValues.put("qty", int_edttxt);
                orderValues.put("amount", amount);
                dh.insert(DatabaseHelpereKOT.RESTAURANT_menu_order, null,
                        orderValues);

                block_not_chk_for_first_click = 2;
                System.out.println("block not chk after insertion"
                        + block_not_chk_for_first_click);
                System.out.println("data inserted at order");
                String msg = "Menu Item Added Successfully";
                Message msgObject = new Message();
                msgObject.what = 1;
                msgObject.obj = msg;
                addMenuItemHandler.sendMessage(msgObject);

            }
        }
    }

    public Handler addMenuItemHandler = new Handler() {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
            if (msg.what == 1) {
                System.out.println("inside handler");
                Toast.makeText(mContext, (String) msg.obj, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        };

    };

    public static class ViewHolder {

        private TextView tvTitle;
        private TextView tvPrice;
        private TextView tvDescription;
        private ImageView imType;
        private EditText edtxt_qty;
        private ImageView addImage;

        public ImageView getAddImage() {
            return addImage;
        }

        public void setAddImage(ImageView imageView) {
            addImage = imageView;
        }

        public TextView getTvTitle() {
            return tvTitle;
        }

        public void setTvTitle(TextView tvTitle) {
            this.tvTitle = tvTitle;
        }

        public TextView getTvPrice() {
            return tvPrice;
        }

        public void setTvPrice(TextView tvPrice) {
            this.tvPrice = tvPrice;
        }

        public TextView getTvDescription() {
            return tvDescription;
        }

        public void setTvDescription(TextView tvDescription) {
            this.tvDescription = tvDescription;
        }

        public ImageView getImType() {
            return imType;
        }

        public void setImType(ImageView imType) {
            this.imType = imType;
        }

        public EditText getEdtTxtQty() {

            return edtxt_qty;
        }

        public void setEdtxtQty(EditText edtTxtqty) {
            this.edtxt_qty = edtTxtqty;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bare minimum example of using tags, however it might not relate much to the above question, the purpose is to demonstrate the usage.

```
 private class CurAdapter extends CursorAdapter implements SectionIndexer{

    AlphabetIndexer mAlphabetIndexer;

    public CurAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int flags) {
        super(context, c, flags);

        mAlphabetIndexer = new AlphabetIndexer(c,
                c.getColumnIndex("Name"),"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ");
        mAlphabetIndexer.setCursor(c);

    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

        ((TextView) view.getTag(R.id.textView1)).setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Name")));

        String manuplate = dateConvert(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("BirthDate")));
        if(manuplate.contains("0001")){
            manuplate = manuplate.replace("0001", "");
        }

        ((TextView) view.getTag(R.id.textView2)).setText((manuplate));
        ((TextView) view.getTag(R.id.textView1)).setTypeface(tf, Typeface.BOLD);
        ((TextView) view.getTag(R.id.textView2)).setTypeface(tf1); 

        String image = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("imageUri"));
        System.out.println("Image Uri is:"+image);
        if(image.contains("jpg") || image.contains("png")){


            /*  File IMG_FILE = new File(image);
            Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inScaled = false;
            options.inDither = false;
            options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(IMG_FILE.getAbsolutePath(), options);*/

            File f = new File(image);
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath());
            ((ImageView) view.getTag(R.id.imageView1)).setImageBitmap(bmp); 


        }else{
            Uri IMAGE_URI = Uri.parse(image);
            IMAGE_URI= Uri.withAppendedPath(IMAGE_URI, Contacts.Photo.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
            try{
                ((ImageView) view.getTag(R.id.imageView1)).setImageURI(IMAGE_URI);

            }catch (Exception e){
                System.out.println(e);
            }

        }
        ///Buffered stream handling if no image is present display a default image. 
        if (((ImageView) view.getTag(R.id.imageView1)).getBackground()== null){
            ((ImageView) view.getTag(R.id.imageView1)).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.default_img); 
        }
    }
    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.contacts_list, null);

        TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        TextView tv1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        view.setTag(R.id.textView1, tv);
        view.setTag(R.id.textView2, tv1);
        view.setTag(R.id.imageView1, iv);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public int getPositionForSection(int sectionIndex) {

        return mAlphabetIndexer.getPositionForSection(sectionIndex);
    }

    @Override
    public int getSectionForPosition(int position) {

        return mAlphabetIndexer.getSectionForPosition(position);
    }

    @Override
    public Object[] getSections() {

        return mAlphabetIndexer.getSections();
    }
}
```